# Elasticsearch - generating nested field from foreach expression using grok

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating an ingest pipeline to generate a nested field called "information_nested" (elasticsearch version 6.8). The minimal working example is the following.

**Sample input:**

```
"info": Information: [Books:0    Pencils:387    Pens:8, Books:15    Pencils:3147    Pens:8, Books:0    Pencils:3    Pens:845] end.
```

**Desired output:**

```
information_nested : {
  {
   Books: 0,
   Pencils: 387,
   Pens: 8
  },
  {
   Books: 15,
   Pencils: 3147,
   Pens: 8
  },
  {
   Books: 0,
   Pencils: 3,
   Pens: 845
  }
}
```

**Here is what I tried so far:**

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/info_pipeline
{
  "description": "",
  "processors": [
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "_source.info",
        "patterns": [
          "Information: \\[%{DATA:information}\\] end"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "split": {
        "field": "information",
        "separator": ", "
      }
    },
    {
      "foreach": {
        "field": "information",
        "processor": {
          "grok": {
            "field": "_ingest._value",
            "patterns": [
              "Books:%{NUMBER:books:int}\\tPencils:%{NUMBER:pencils}\\tPens:%{NUMBER:pens}"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "information"
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "information_nested",
        "value": [
          {
            "books": "{{books}}",
            "pencils": "{{pencils}}",
            "pens": "{{pens}}"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that I only get the last item in the nested field "information_nested".

I know that this is due to the foreach but I don't know how to solve it.